# How Can I design an area that JS should be applied?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for a way to apply JQuery function to a particular division.

My code following applies all checkboxes named chk[].
but I would like to have it checked only in `<div id="part_1"> </div>`

```
$(function() {
    $('#all').on('click', function() {
//I want to apply "checked" only to from 1A - 1D.
      $("input[name='chk[]']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("input[name='chk[]']").on('click', function() {
      if ($('#boxes :checked').length == $('#boxes :input').length) {
        $('#all').prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $('#all').prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
  });
```

```
<label for="all"><input type="checkbox" name="allChecked" id="all">ALL</label>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('debug.store') }}">
<div id="part_1">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="A">1A</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="B">1B</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="C">1C</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="D">1D</label>
</div>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('debug.store') }}">
<div id="part_2">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="A">2A</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="B">2B</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="C">2C</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="D">2D</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#part_1 input[name='chk[]']")`
This will select input checkboxes named chk[] that are children of any element with the ID of part_1